# Blocking dangerous IPs for accessing a resource

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, security, iis

## Environment

My IIS host an WebApp with WebService resources.

- ...
- myWebService.asmx
- myWebService.svc
- ...

## Problem

Same bad guys, try to block server accessing the public resources with theirs bots.

## Applied solution

1. I Build a filter:

   ```cs
   public class BadGuysFilter
   {
       private class BadGuy
       {
           public BadGuy()
           {
               Visits = 0;
               FirstSuspiciousVisit = DateTime.Now;
           }

           public int Visits;
           public DateTime FirstSuspiciousVisit;
       }

       private static volatile Dictionary<string, BadGuy> _blackList = new Dictionary<string, BadGuy>();
       private static int _visitsLimit = 10;
       private static int _minutsLimit = 10;
       private static int _removeFromBlackListMinutesLimit = 30;

       public static void Init(int visitsLimit = 10, int minutsLimit = 10, int removeFromBlackListMinutesLimit = 30)
       {
           _visitsLimit = visitsLimit;
           _minutsLimit = minutsLimit;
           _removeFromBlackListMinutesLimit = removeFromBlackListMinutesLimit;
       }

       public static bool IsBadGuy()
       {
           return IsBadGuy(HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress);
       }
       public static bool IsBadGuy(string ip)
       {
           if (HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated /*|| HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod.ToUpper() == "POST"*/)
               return false;

           if (_blackList.Keys.Any(k => k == ip))
           {
               _blackList[ip].Visits++;

               if (_blackList[ip].FirstSuspiciousVisit < DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-_removeFromBlackListMinutesLimit))
                   _blackList.Remove(ip);
               else if (_blackList[ip].FirstSuspiciousVisit < DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-_minutsLimit))
               {
                   _blackList[ip].Visits = 0;
                   _blackList[ip].FirstSuspiciousVisit = DateTime.Now;
               }
               else if (_blackList[ip].Visits > _visitsLimit)
               {
                   _blackList[ip].FirstSuspiciousVisit = DateTime.Now;
                   return true;
               }
           }
           else
               _blackList.Add(ip, new BadGuy());

           return false;
       }
       public static void Punish()
       {
           var res = HttpContext.Current.Response;
           res.Clear();
           res.StatusCode = 429;
           res.StatusDescription = "TOO MANY REQUESTS: Your application is sending too many simultaneous requests.";
           res.End();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Use filter in **Global.asax**

   ```cs
   void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) {
       if(BadGuysFilter.IsBadGuy())
           BadGuysFilter.Punish();

       // do stuff //
   }

   void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) {
       var app = (HttpApplication)sender;

       if (app.Context.Response.StatusCode == 429) // "TOO MANY REQUESTS"
           return;

       // do stuff //
   }
   ```

## Question

**Is this an enough safe solution? Or maybe there is another way?**

Edite:
*"don't block at the resource itself. block farther upstream, e.g. at the firewall. – Marc B"
Yes, you're right. This is final solution, but before apply it i need intermediate solution to defend my server. I forgot to mention this thing. – Artiom*

Comment: don't block at the resource itself. block farther upstream, e.g. at the firewall.

Comment: as @MarcB says, this solution is going to tie up IIS resources for every blocked request, which is not going to help if they're doing DDOS attack.

Comment: Yes, you're right. This is final solution, but before apply it i need intermediate solution to defend my server. I forgot to mention this thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use IIS Dynamic IP restriction module (from Microsoft):

http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/dynamic-ip-restrictions

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments above.  You need to block ddos further upstream otherwise you application is still going to be servicing each request.

This type of approach appears to lack any persistence.  Therefore, when they bombard your system and you recycle the app pools, it will reset.  On the other hand, the firewall apprach lacks the flexibility to remove after a certain time...I think.

That said, if you need to handle suspicious requests of a different nature such as too many request to the login page but not the home page or something then this could be a viable solution.

It is really just considering all of your goals and understanding the risks and limitations.